# Cookie Error while PayPal payment

Tags: cookies, paypal

The PayPal integration is working fine with my website so far. But today the only issue that I am having is that after redirect on the Paypal, I’m getting an error that says:

"Cookies are disabled. Many features PayPal need cookies enabled . Please enable cookies in your browser. Then go back again , and complete the transaction with PayPal".

Cookies in my browsers are enabled.

I found some information here:
https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/My-Feedback-for-PayPal-Archive/Paypal-Please-fix-the-cookie-problem-it-s-been-years/td-p/462983

But for all browsers, this problem can't be resolved by clearing or deleting cookies.

Please help.

Comment: I checked this on other hosts but the problem persists

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same issue at the moment. I was suspicious of the message given that I can clear the cookies set by that page, and then when I come back it sets new ones. So cookies clearly aren't "off".

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now I'm sure that's not problem on my platform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything was working just fine until today:

- I cleared the cookies and made sure that are enabled on my browser.
- I tried to test it on other browsers and even going incognito.

But the problems persists. This is definitely a paypal's issue.